# Cloning a private repo in Github Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am trying to clone another private repo in Github actions. I have set `SECRET_USER` and `SECRET_PASSWORD` in the secrets of the repo I'm running the actions on. In actions I'm running the command

```
git clone https://$SECRET_USER:$SECRET_PASSWORD@github.com/other-organization/other-repo.git
```

but getting the error

```
Cloning into 'other-repo'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/other-organization/other-repo.git/'
##[error]Process completed with exit code 128.
```

in Github Actions although I've verified that the user can access `https://github.com/other-organization/other-repo` (which is obviously not the real URL of the internal repo).

Comment: Does `git clone https://$SECRET_USER:$SECRET_PASSWORD@github.com/other-organization/other-repo.git` work for you on your local machine?

Comment: Secrets should be referenced like this `${{ secrets.SECRET_USER }}` unless your `run` step is setting `env` variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I added a git configuration step to my `go.yml` that did the trick:

```
- name: Configure git
  env:
    TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
  run: git config --global url."https://${TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

where `ACCESS_TOKEN` is a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) I added instead of the username/password combo because the private repo I was trying to access required an SSO enabled token to access it instead of the username/password combination. This was, unfortunately, not obvious from the error message and required talking to people to learn this information.

Comment: Be aware of using access tokens in a corporate environment, that can be exposed easily. Prefer using deploy keys.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [git-credential-store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) to save your credentials in file, so then git can use it if needed.
There is no need to modify urls in (my case) Podfile/specfile.

```
git config --global credential.helper store
echo "https://$SECRET_USER:$SECRET_PASSWORD@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials
```

I have mixed feelings about saving such data in plaintext file, but on CI/CD machines imo it'd fine. I use it [here](https://github.com/an-organization-created-for-testing/cocoapods-app).

Answer (score -1):

1. Create new personal token with name USER_TOKEN
2. Use the token created.

   ```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Git Bolivia
        run: |
          git --version
          git clone https://${{ secrets.USER_TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/Organization/repository.git
   ```