# How to clone private spec repo in CocoaPods within GitHub Actions?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, github-actions

I have a private CocoaPods spec repo that my project relies on to run `pod install`.

I'm trying to automate my build process using GitHub Actions. However, since the spec repo is private, I'm having trouble getting access to it in this other project.

I have tried the following code:

```
      - name: Clone private-cocoapods-spec
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: fishcharlie/Private-CocoaPods-Spec
          ref: refs/heads/master
          # GitHub's personal access token with access to `my-organization/awesome-action`
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          persist-credentials: false
          path: /Users/runner/.cocoapods/repos/private-cocoapods-spec
```

Sadly this produces the following error:

> Repository path '/Users/runner/.cocoapods/repos/private-cocoapods-spec' is not under '/Users/runner/work/Project/Project'

I also tried the following based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60548651/894067):

```
      - name: Configure git
        env:
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
        run: git config --global url."https://${TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

However this didn't work either and produced the following error:

```
Cloning spec repo `private-cocoapods-spec` from `git@github.com:fishcharlie/Private-CocoaPods-Spec.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `git@github.com:fishcharlie/Private-CocoaPods-Spec.git ` named `private-cocoapods-spec`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/runner/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I'm assuming this is because I'm trying to use SSH instead of HTTPS to authenticate.

What is the best method to achieve this and have access to my private cocoapods-spec so that my `pod install` command will succeed?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/.github/workflows/generate_issues.yml#L22

Comment: @PaulBeusterien That is for generating a nightly report using a custom GitHub Action. Has no relation to what I'm trying to do. If you dig into that GitHub Action, it takes in that as a parameter, and runs a Dockerfile to run some Ruby commands. Not at all related to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using credentials explicit, you can use git-credentials-store:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
echo "https://username:${{ secrets.TOKEN }}@github.com" > ~/.git-credentials
```

In Podfile and podspec I use only `https://` links (without username/password). With git credentials configuration `pod install` is enough to get `spec` and `pod` repositories.

I built it on GitHub Actions [here](https://github.com/an-organization-created-for-testing).

Using SSH is quite problematic - if you use deployment keys, it's not possible to distinguish which key should be used to spec/pod repo.
The only way to do it is to change host in `~/.ssh/config`. I think it's a wrong way, especially if you see how the configuration in podspec and podfile needs to be to make it working.

Comment: So changing the URL structure slightly: `${TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com` this step worked and was successful. However when doing `pod install`, it failed and tried to reclone the spec repo with a `-1` appended to the end of name: `Cloning spec repo private-cocoapods-spec-1 from git@github.com:fishcharlie/Private-CocoaPods-Spec.git`

Comment: @CharlieFish I worked out a solution, check the commend and repos linked

Comment: @CharlieFish does the answer suit the bounty?