# Periodically clone external repo with github actions and set it as a private repo

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to set a GitHub action that periodically clones an external repository (e.g., `targetuser/targetrepo` and for which I have a personal access token).

The GitHub action runs smoothly, but I have no clue *where* the repository is being cloned: I cannot see it in my GitHub account.
Also, I would like the cloned repository to be set as private.

This is my `main.yml` file based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60527677/cloning-a-private-repo-in-github-actions):

```yaml
name: mainAction
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  "*/5 * * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs: 
  copyRepo:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Copy repo
      env:
        ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      run: git clone "https://"$ACCESS_TOKEN"@github.com/targetuser/targetrepo.git"
```

---

**Edit**
I would like to have a copy of the GitHub repository on my account, and not just in the runner's "container".

Comment: As you used a Github Action runner to clone the repo, the cloned repo will be located at the `github.workspace` (aka repository root) of the repository workflow (enabled with the `action/checkout` action). But as you don't perform any other action, it won't be persisted at the end of the workflow run.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I am very new to github but I think I get what you mean. From that point, is there a way to execute a workflow that is located within the cloned repository?

Comment: You want to run a workflow from another repository inside a workflow run after having cloned this other repository; did I understand correctly? Depending on what you want to achieve, it could maybe be possible to do the same thing without having to clone the repository, using a dispatch event for example.

Comment: When you execute an action, a running is created. That runner is a Docker container. When you **git clone**, you are copying files to the container. When the runner finishes execution the files are deleted. You must save the results of **git clone** someplace. Your question is not clear on what **set it as a private repo** means. Do you want to create a new repo each time or update an existing repo? Edit your question with details.

Comment: @JohnHanley I updated the post to specify what I am looking for. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Your last edit does not clarify what I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have a copy of the github repository on my account, and not just in the runner's "container".

That would be better address by a *mirroring* GitHub Action, like [`wearerequired/git-mirror-action`](https://github.com/wearerequired/git-mirror-action), or better, in your case (using tokens): [`pkgstore/github-action-mirror`](https://github.com/pkgstore/github-action-mirror)

```yaml
name: "Repository Mirror: GitHub"

on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  "*/5 * * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  mirror:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: "Mirror"
    steps:
      - uses: pkgstore/github-action-mirror@main
        with:
          source_repo: "https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}.git"
          source_user: "${{ secrets.MIRROR_SOURCE_USER_GITHUB }}"
          source_token: "${{ secrets.MIRROR_SOURCE_TOKEN_GITHUB }}"
          target_repo: "${{ secrets.MIRROR_TARGET_URL_GITHUB }}"
          target_user: "${{ secrets.MIRROR_TARGET_USER_GITHUB }}"
          target_token: "${{ secrets.MIRROR_TARGET_TOKEN_GITHUB }}"
```

That way, you can send the source repository to a *private* repository of yours.